# Saving a customer's info so I can accept bitcoin

Tags: business, recurring-payments

I have a business that basically works using a subscription (I'm simplifying here). I see that Stripe accepts Bitcoin, but it's for a one time payment. Is there any way to save a customer's Bitcoin info, or is it just for one time payments? The nice thing about a credit card is you can keep charging it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to initiate a payment request in bitcoin?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1490/is-there-a-way-to-initiate-a-payment-request-in-bitcoin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe doesn't support recurrent Bitcoin payments.

> A receiver can only be used for a single payment—Stripe does not
>   currently support recurring or repeated payments with Bitcoin.

[source](https://stripe.com/docs/bitcoin).

[Coinbase](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/merchants/recurring-payments) does.

Comment: One caveat: as Murch pointed out bitcoin transactions must be pushed by the payer. Coinbase can only offer recurrent payments as long as the payer has a sufficient balance in the payer's account.

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin transactions are "pushed" by the payer. There is no way for the recipient to "pull" payments.

You should use a new address for each customer. That way you can see who paid their subscription fee by checking which address received the payment. However, the customer would still have to repeat the payment every time.